# Javascript Replace Single Quote Not Working

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am trying to achieve something very simple and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

See the string below;

```
My Name St Eugene’s Cathedral
```

I would like it to be;

```
my-name-st-eugene-s-cathedral
```

I need to remove all spaces and single quotes, replace with a hyphen and convert to lowercase.

My code so far is;

```js
var str = "My Name St Eugene’s Cathedral"
str = str.replace(/'| /g,'-').toLowerCase(); 
alert(str)
```

Link to fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/8z2jseyr/1/

Comment: One is `’` and the other is `'`

Comment: `str = str.replace(/'| |’/g,'-').toLowerCase(); `

Comment: how about `str.replace(/\W+/g,'-').toLowerCase();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `’` not `'`. If you want `'` also when making slugs add that one also with another `|'`

```js
var str = "My Name St Eugene’s Cathedral"
str = str.replace(/’| /g,'-').toLowerCase(); 
console.log(str)
```

for both `'` and `’`

```js
var str = "My Name St Eugene’s Cathedral"
str = str.replace(/'|’| /g,'-').toLowerCase(); 
console.log(str)
```

**With Character Class**

```js
var str = "My Name St Eugene’s Cathedral"
str = str.replace(/[’\s']/g,'-').toLowerCase(); 
console.log(str)
```

Comment: Or `str.replace(/['’\s]/g,'-')`

Answer (score 0):

There is also a utility function in lodash doing this:
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#kebabCase

aka [kebab case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Special_case_styles) conversion